# A way to translate images?

Tags: python-3.x, image, translation, google-translate, yandex

In Python I am attempting to translate Arabic characters within a image. I can provide the language 'source' type (Arabic) and 'destination' (English). Is there a python library or API that is free that I can use for this? I.e that provides a service like https://translate.google.com, that allows for cloud image translation (the uploading of images containing non-translated characters) and downloading of images containing the destination characters translated within the image? Or a library to do this locally within my system (i.e. detect Arabic characters from an image containing Arabic text, extract the Arabic characters, for using cloud translation services (e.g. google translate) and then modify the image containing Arabic characters with the newly translated English characters? So, my goal is to modify/replace the Arabic characters within an image containing Arabic characters with English characters that are the translated characters of the original/extracted Arabic characters. I know Yandex / https://translate.yandex.com/ocr allows for this however you must pay for their translation API. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if there is support for Arabic, there are libraries like OpenCV2 for python and pytesseract to extract text from image. Then you can use another library like translate to finish the process from there. https://pypi.org/project/translate/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).